# NotificationBuilder.setProgress doesn't do anything on 2.3.5

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm using the v13 support library. I build a progress notification with the notification builder and .setProgress.  it works just fine on a 4.2.2 device, but on 2.3.5 nothing is shown.

is this the normal behavior ?

```
mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

mBuilder.setContentTitle("Photo Upload")
            .setContentText("Upload in progress")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_upload)
            .setOngoing(true);

.
.

mBuilder.setProgress(100, prog, false);
mNotifyManager.notify(sNotificationID, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like on Gingerbread (and below) isn't supported, and it's not documented either.
Here is the actual code from the support library which creates an instance of [`Notification`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html):

```
static class NotificationCompatImplBase implements NotificationCompatImpl {
    public Notification build(Builder b) {
        Notification result = (Notification) b.mNotification;
        result.setLatestEventInfo(b.mContext, b.mContentTitle,
                b.mContentText, b.mContentIntent);
        // translate high priority requests into legacy flag
        if (b.mPriority > PRIORITY_DEFAULT) {
            result.flags |= FLAG_HIGH_PRIORITY;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The only viable option is using a custom [`RemoteView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html). You might want to look at the Android source code for a sample progress notification layout.

Answer (score 0):

> it works just fine on a 4.2.2 device, but on 2.3.5 nothing is shown

Android 1.x and 2.x (especially Gingerbread) requires from `Notification` contentIntent (also empty). So create empty action like this:

```
PendingIntent action = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(<context>, 0, 
                                new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
...
mBuilder.setContentIntent(action);
```

And now it should works.

Comment: Actualy this makes the notify shows up, but the progressbar is not working because the version.